# Replacement swivel for swing-top reading table

Tags: furniture, replacement, hardware

Ten years ago I got a Levenger swing-top wooden reading table.  This is a chair-side reading table whose flat oval-shaped top can be swung horizontally over my chair to serve as a stable platform for a laptop.

It has been wonderful but has had one significant problem, the plates that hold the top to the table while allowing it to swivel have ball bearings in them, that, over time, have all fallen out.  Now its all wobbly and unstable, i would replace the whole table but Levenger no longer makes it, and i have never seen anything else like it nor nearly as nice (and I have looked).

So instead I thought I would just replace the part that has failed.  as you can see below, it is a pair of 4 inch square metal plates bound together at the center, with matching circular tracks to hold the ball-bearings.

[image]

And here is my problem, I cannot find this part, nor any reasonable replacement anywhere on the internet.  I have been googling "360 degree swivel mount" and though i have found several items, they are all way too large.  The smallest i have found so far is 6 inches with holes set at least 5 inches apart.  My item is only 4 inches on a side with the holes only 3 inches apart (obverse side here):

[image]

Can anyone help me by suggesting one of the following:

- Any place that sells this item, or an equivalent, or
- what is the correct term is should be searching for (I suspect this is my problem), or
- some other alternative solution

I should mention that I am hesitant to just try a larger pair of plates here for two reasons, first the swing top is only 1/2 inch thick, and I am concerned that these larger items, sold as swivel mounts for boat seats, will require mounting holes deeper than that.  And secondly, that i may not have the room (or skill) to properly make new holes for the screws and mount it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Try "lazy susan bearing", then look for the small ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**4" flat square lazy susan bearing** will get you what you need.

Turntable bearing may also work without offending hardworking suzys.